# MongoDB Embedded polymorphic objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a object similar to this:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Bike), typeof(Car), typeof(Van))]
public class Vehicle
{
    public List<Wheel> wheels;
}

public class Bike: Vehicle
{

}

public class Car: Vehicle
{

}

public class Van: Vehicle
{

}

[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(WheelA), typeof(WheelB))]
public class Wheel
{

}

public class WheelA: Wheel
{
    private int Propa;
}

public class WheelB: Wheel
{
    private int Propb;
}
```

I have collection named vehicle and store all derived objects in this collection. Vehicle has embedded object collection for Type 'Wheel'. If my collection has different types of wheels, those types do not get deserialized. Is there a way I can use polymorphism for embedded objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try registering the derived types like:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<WheelA>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<WheelB>();
```

or like:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(WheelA), typeof(WheelB))]
public class Wheel
```

**UPDATE:** While creating a test project I realised: you need to **make the properties public**.
MongoDB can't set them, if they're not accessable.

Here's the test code:

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Polymorphic_objects_should_deserialize()
    {
        var database = MongoDatabase.Create("connection_string");
        var collection = database.GetCollection("vehicles");

        var car = new Car
        {
            wheels = new List<Wheel>
                       {
                           new WheelA {propA = 123},
                           new WheelB {propB = 456}
                       }
        };
        collection.Insert(car);

        var fetched = collection.AsQueryable<Car>()
                        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == car.Id);

        Assert.IsNotNull(fetched.wheels);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, fetched.wheels.Count);

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(fetched.wheels[0], typeof(WheelA));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(fetched.wheels[1], typeof(WheelB));

        Assert.AreEqual(123, (fetched.wheels[0] as WheelA).propA);
        Assert.AreEqual(456, (fetched.wheels[1] as WheelB).propB);
    }
}
```

The entities are identical to your listing, except for `Propa` & `Propb`, which are made public.
I also added an `Id` field to `Vehicle` to be able to test it.
The test is green.

Comment: have tried bsondiscriminator and bsonknowtypes.. did not seem to work i think it is because the objects are embedded..

Comment: +1 The `BsonDiscriminator` is crucial. Great answer.

Comment: I've use[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)] insted of [BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]and it's work! Thanks!

Comment: and they have to have a setter also. They can be private though.

Comment: @David, Is there an option to short it? I have one class with many (20) children and I don't like that I have to explicitly write one by one

Answer (score 1):

Look BsonDiscriminator attribute
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Polymorphicclassesanddiscriminators